# Crop image with full width

Tags: media-library, cropping

Sometimes I need to crop images' heights in wordpress media library. When I try to crop the height it always decreases the width of cropped image by 2px. See the screenshot below. The original image is 600px wide. While cropping it takes 2px less width leaving 598px wide images. I tried to add 600 in selection fields but it automatically makes it 598.

[image]

Is there any solution to this issue? I don't know if wordpress sets it this way or its a bug. I want the width to remain same as original.

Comment: Hm, even when you set Selection to 600x600?